# Secure Encrypted Chat Protocol

Tags: cryptography, key-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to negotiate a secret between 2 parties with no prior knowledge?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/is-there-a-way-to-negotiate-a-secret-between-2-parties-with-no-prior-knowledge)

Imagine two clients who want to establish a secure connection over a server. Both clients have a trustworthy public key from the server, so they can establish a secure connection to the server. If the clients would now exchange public keys, the server could obviously do a man-in-the-middle-attack. Is there any way to prevent this? (So that, if the establishment of the connection succeeds, the clients are guaranteed to have a secure channel and the server cannot eavesdrop.)

Comment: So the answer is pretty much: It's impossible, that is, there is no known method. (Without cheesy things like waiting a constant amount of time.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could probably do a [Diffie Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to create a temporary session key and use that to symmetrically-encrypt the communications.

Comment: Please include in your answer why the server is now prevented to do a man-in-the-middle-attack. :)